# pulseaudio Denied access to client with invalid authentication data

Tags: pulseaudio, authentication, restricted-access, protocol

keep getting repeating pulseaudio message in syslog!

```
Mar  2 18:43:14 itc2 pulseaudio.pulseaudio[27388]: W: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Denied access to client with invalid authentication data.
Mar  2 18:43:16 itc2 pulseaudio.pulseaudio[27388]: W: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Denied access to client with invalid authentication data.
Mar  2 18:43:19 itc2 pulseaudio.pulseaudio[27388]: W: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Denied access to client with invalid authentication data.
Mar  2 18:43:21 itc2 pulseaudio.pulseaudio[27388]: W: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Denied access to client with invalid authentication data.
Mar  2 18:43:24 itc2 pulseaudio.pulseaudio[27388]: W: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Denied access to client with invalid authentication data.
```

tried adding anonymous=1 to /etc/pulse/system.pa

```
load-module module-native-protocol-unix auth-anonymous=1
```

tried adding username to pulse group

they are not helping

tried killing them and they reappear with syslog

```
benf     26934     1  0 18:36 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
benf     26984 26934  0 18:36 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pulse/gconf-helper
root     27388     1  0 18:39 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /snap/pulseaudio/10/bin/pulseaudio
root     27447 27388  0 18:39 ?        00:00:00 /snap/pulseaudio/10/usr/bin/pulseaudio --exit-idle-time=-1 --disallow-exit=yes --system -F /snap/pulseaudio/10/etc/pulse/default.pa -p /snap/pulseaudio/10/usr/lib/pulse-8.0/modules -n
```

sounds works with setting tests, but one java apps sends crash message and sound dies on them!

syslog keeps with error message even without any apps running just gnome desktop -ubuntu 18

Comment: Remove snap version from pulseaudio

Comment: sudo apt-get remove snapd showed removing   gnome-software-plugin-snap snapd
Removing gnome-software-plugin-snap (3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.15) ...
Removing snapd (2.48.3+18.04) ...
Stopping snap.pulseaudio.pulseaudio.service
Stopping unit snap.pulseaudio.pulseaudio.service
Waiting until unit snap.pulseaudio.pulseaudio.service is stopped [attem    pt 1]
snap.pulseaudio.pulseaudio.service is stopped
thanks @nobody , syslog clean, no error I can see..will continue to  monitor
ps shows gdm and my userid for pulseaudio process owner instead of root for snap!